# DataGridView, some doubles formatted as exponential

Tags: c#, parsing, datagridview, datatable, double

I have a DataGridView with a DataTable that's being filled before as a DataSource. Unfortunately some of the doubles are being formatted as exponential and I can't figure out how to change this:

[image]
The code looks as follows...

Creating the DataTable (which will later on be the DataSource):

```
void CreateDataTable()
    {
        logFileDataTable = new DataTable();

        logFileDataTable.Columns.Add("line", typeof(int));
        logFileDataTable.Columns.Add("time", typeof(string));
        logFileDataTable.Columns.Add("delay", typeof(double));
        logFileDataTable.Columns.Add("thread", typeof(string));
        logFileDataTable.Columns.Add("task", typeof(string));
        logFileDataTable.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
        logFileDataTable.Columns.Add("message", typeof(string));
    }
```

Fillig a tmp variable and converting string to double:

```
double logDelay = 0;
if (match.Groups[4].Value != null && match.Groups[4].Value != "")
                    {
                        logDelay = double.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value.Replace(".", ","));
                    }
```

Adding the row to the DataTable:

```
logFileDataTable.Rows.Add(logZeile, logZeit, logDelay, logThread, logTask, logValue, logMeldung);
```

Assigning the DataSource:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = logFileDataTable;
```

As the DataTable column is double as well I can't use any string format to change this. Anyone help out there? :)

Cheers

Edit: 
Debugging the code shows that the value is correct before parsing:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format the column itself on your DataGridView component, like this:

```
var delayColumnName = "delay";
var numberWithDecimalsFormat = "N7";

table.Columns.Add(delayColumnName, typeof(double));
table.Rows.Add(0.000098);

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
dataGridView1.Columns[delayColumnName].DefaultCellStyle.Format = numberWithDecimalsFormat;
```

In this way you will format what is being displayed.
So, if the user enters a new number, it will also be formatted as specified.

Please take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) for more formatting options.

Comment: I had to use dataGridView.Columns["delay"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.000000"; to make it work, but your suggestion was absolutely right. Many thanks :) wonder why I didn't find the format property...